# Combining SVG images programmatically

Tags: scripting, svg, batch-processing

I have a program that generates multiple SVG files in batch, which I then need to be able to combine (tiled) into one file, with a set whitespace and set width in cm (or mm).

I need either an existing script or a pointer to which libraries and languages I can use to accomplish this. Any suggestions where to start?

Answer (score 9):

Here are some tools which can help you to create a *SVG* sprite sheet from your *svg* files:

**[SVG STACK](https://github.com/astraw/svg_stack)**

**[SVG UTILS](https://github.com/btel/svg_utils)**

And then you can clean up your svg when all done with a tool like

**[SCOUR](http://codedread.com/scour/)**

Answer (score 2):

Yes as [@victor-henriquez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12687803/1240387) noted you can use `montage` but it’s a bit tricky, I got into it by activating the `-verbose` output and see that it created an `inkscape` command and analysing that solved this issue for me.

```
montage -version
# Version: ImageMagick 7.0.7-31 Q16 x86_64 20180506
```

I wanted …

- … to label desktop icons: use `-label` and `-pointsize` (tricky to get font size correct via pointsize but depending on density)
- … to increase `-density` (it’s tricky to find a suitable number for the output)
- … to stack and tile them orderly: use `-tile 15x30` (here 15 columns x 30 rows)
- … to add a margin on each sub-image: use `-geometry '+40+0'` (adds 40px horizontally but 0px vertically)

The resulting command was (add `-verbose` to get detailed processing information):

```
montage -label '%f' -pointsize 2 -density 300 *.svg \
  -tile 15x30 \
  -geometry '+40+0' \
 ./papirus-icons-mimetypes.png
```

If you specify additionally the desired output pixel size geometry, eg. 96 pixels by 96 pixels `-geometry '96x96+40+0'`, it becomes even more complex to understand what `-density` plays a role at. I failed to figure it out deeply ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I used Victor gem https://github.com/DannyBen/victor

```
first_svg = File.open("first.svg").read
second_svg = File.open("second.svg").read

first_content = first_svg.split("\n")[1..-2].join(", ")
second_content = second_svg.split("\n")[1..-2].join(", ")

svg = Victor::SVG.new width: "100%", height: "100%"
svg << first_content
svg << second_content

svg.save 'final.svg'
```

Answer (score -2):

You can have a look to montage, from ImageMagick: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/

You can build your script around it.

Comment: Doesn't seem like montage supports vector graphics.

Comment: It supports SVG. I've used montage with them without problems. _ImageMagick® is a software suite to create, edit, compose, or convert bitmap images. It can read and write images in a variety of formats (over 100) including DPX, EXR, GIF, JPEG, JPEG-2000, PDF, PhotoCD, PNG, Postscript, SVG, and TIFF._

Comment: But as far as I can see I would need to convert the data to raster to use montage? I need SVG output as well.

Comment: When montage is used with a SVG output, it creates a valid SVG which embeds a base64-encoded raster image.